# « Il a des qualités de dirigeant » ou « Il a des qualités d'un dirigeant »

Tags: grammaire, articles

Quelle est la bonne formulation ?
« Il a des qualités de dirigeant » ou « Il a des qualités d'un dirigeant ».

Je veux dire « He has qualities of a leader ».

Des recherches sur Google renvoient des exemples pour « qualités de dirigeant » et « qualités d'un dirigeant ».

Answer (score 6):

I think using "dirigeant" for "leader" is not the most approriate.

"Dirigeant" is closer to "manager" while "leader" should be translated as "meneur".

"Dirigeant" is someone who manages, who directs people as he has some authority over them and it is very often used for someone higher in the hierarchy of an organization.

"Meneur" would refer to someone at the same hierarchical level but who naturally guides the people by whom he has been implicitly appointed as the person to follow.

We can use the examples of a music band's leader who is one of the band member while the band's manager is not.

So to translate "He has qualities of a leader", I suggest:

> "Il a les qualités d'un meneur"

or

> "Il a des qualités de meneur"

The first suggestion implies he has all the qualities required to be a leader while the second one means he has some of the qualities but not all of them.

Concerning the difference between "les [...] d'un" and "des [...] de" it is because when you mention "les" it refers to the quality of a particular leader so "un" whereas when you say "des" it does not.

Comment: Is "Il a des qualités de meneur." grammatically correct? I have heard that the article is always important?

Comment: @Onaeu Selon moi, dans meneur, d’hommes est forcément implicite puisque qu’il s’agit d’une qualité de relation humaine. Un meneur ne le serait pas sans ses suiveurs. Cependant ajouter d’hommes me donne le sentiment de passer à une échelle supérieure. Ainsi le meneur du groupe de musique ou de l’équipe sportive est un meneur de groupe mais pas d’hommes. Je me souviens avoir lu dans une revue économique des managers citant des meneurs d’hommes: M.L. King, Napoléon, Mao Zedong, Gengis Khan, Hitler ou Mandela. Ainsi meneur d’hommes est souvent associé à une personne ayant impact sur les masses.

Comment: @Onaeu S’il est vrai qu’avec les exemples que vous donnez, meneur semble être un terme péjoratif, je ne pense pas que ce le soit réellement. En effet, dans ces exemples on associe le meneur au trouble-fête  qui emmène avec lui tout un groupe sans organisation stricte et sans hiérarchie mais je pense qu’un meneur est avant tout quelqu’un qui par son charisme, son exemplarisme et sa force de conviction entraine les gens à le suivre. Aussi, beaucoup de personnes ayant des positions de dirigeant (de parti politique par exemple) sont également des meneurs même si tous les dirigeants n'en sont pas.

Comment: @Onaeu Enfin, pour ce qui est d’un nom qui correspondrait à leadership, je sais que de nos jours nous utilisons couramment le terme anglais leader/leadership qui sont d’ailleurs dans le dictionnaire mais je n’ai aucune proposition, désolé. (Evidemment, l'ensemble de ces commentaires ne sont que mon propre point de vue)

Comment: @seek Yes, "il a des qualités de meneur" is grammatically correct. I don't understand your second question about the importance of the article.

Comment: @Rémi Is the "de meneur" here the replacement of "d'un meneur"? I mean where is the article of "meneur"? It should have one of "un, le," shouldn't it?

Comment: Not necessarily. Here meneur has a function of complementarity of qualités and "de" is a préposition to join thoses words. So the article is only before qualités .

Comment: @Rémi Thanks, I think I get what you say. However, would you be kindly able to provide a reference for this rule you invoke?

Comment: Just Google 'préposition': http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/regles/grammaire/les-prepositions-29.php

Answer (score 0):

> "Il a des qualités d'un dirigeant."

Is correct.

> "Il á des qualités de dirigeant."

Makes my eyes bleed…

a → verbe "avoir" ≠ 
à → préposition

Definitively not the same word ! :)

Same goes for : a et à, ça et çà, la et là

"Il a **des** qualités d'un dirigeant." would mean : "He has some of the qualities that make a leader"

"Il a **les** qualités d’un dirigeant." is more like : "He has all the qualities to be a leader"

Comment: le à, c'est une erreur. Je l'ai corrigé. Merci

Comment: More *de* than *d'un* with *des qualités*.

Answer (score 0):

> "qualités de dirigeant" et "qualités d'un dirigeant".

Both « tournures » are used equally, with the same meaning (AFAIK)

Comment: How is "qualités de dirigeant" correct? Isn't it missing the article? Thanks.

Comment: "Il a les qualités d’un dirigeant" → "He has the qualities of a leader"

No missing article… "of a" litteraly translates in "d’un" (or "d’une")

Comment: Ho… and yes… for "de dirigeant" :) It works like you'd say : Il a des qualités de meneur, (de menteur, tacticien, …) It's absolutly missing the article… But it still wildly used, with the exact same meaning of "d’un" in this case. I hope someone could tell more…